# AWS speed issue

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web

We are facing speed issue on our CRM based website, hosted on AWS EC2 with m3.medium instance.

On this AMI, we have installed IIS 7.0 and MS SQL server(for local database).

And our region is US-West-2 (Oregon).

The site is functioning properly but speed is slow as compared to other hosting provider(Same site is hosted with BigRock with different domain).

There is noticeable speed difference between both website(BigRock and AWS) with same code but different domain.

Can someone please suggest what should we do to increase the speed of our site?

Comment: define "speed". Do you mean time to make a request and receive a full response? Inclusive or exclusive of page requisites? Where are your customers located, and where are you performing the tests from? What do your tests look like when you run them on localhost (e.g., on the EC2 instance itself). I'd suggest using [AB](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) for basic tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have hosted your CRM based website in us-west-2, there will be latency issue which is obvious. If you are planning to serve Indian customers I suggest to host it in the ap-southeast-1 region. Also I guess bigrock data-centers are located in India itself. That's the reason latency will be less. Also considering integrating cloud-front or any CDN if you really want to accelerate the website. Since it's a CRM website you have a look at Elastic Memcache also.

Comment: Thanks Jeevan for quick reply...
Does changing the region will affect speed of website seriously?

Comment: To some extent yes. Also,its not only the region which slows down the speed. Its also the code. So just run any profiling tool like newrelic to access the speed of the application also.

Comment: Thanks Jeevan, speed of web site is increased marginally.
But it cannot access local database from http://localhost/ through browser.
I cant understand what's denying browser to access database.

Comment: Check your firewall settings once and please let me know.

Comment: i have already performed steps listed on [Configure a Windows Firewall for Database Engine Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175043.aspx) for firewall settings...
But no success...

Comment: Its running perfectly while running from visual studio...
But while running from http://localhost/ it cant access database...

Comment: Also I have tried running it while I turned off firewall...
Though it didnt work...

Comment: Check the security group which is attached to the instance. Since MS SQL runs on 1433 port. You need to open the port 1433. Try this and let me know if you have not tried yet.

Comment: I have this security group _type_- all traffic, _Port Range_ - all ports, _Protocol_ - all protocols, Source(0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: that means its open to world...
Still I need to allow 1433 port manually??

Comment: Yes you need to open the port.